# How to check whether the checkboxlist is checked atleast one in Struts2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, struts2, checkboxlist

I'm working in struts2 framework. I have a checkboxlist in my code.

```
<div id="MyCheckbox">
    <td>
      <s:checkboxlist theme="simple" name="claimListView.claimStatus" list="#{'U':'Unprocessed', 'P':'Processed','R':'Routed','S':'Sent'}" id="claimStatus" required="true" value="defaultColor"/>
    </td>
</div>
```

So I want this field to be a required field. I mean the user should select at least one check box. Else an error msg should be throwed and prevent the form to be submitted. How can i achieve this ?

I tried in jquery given below is the code.

```
var n = $("#MyCheckbox input:checked").length;
alert("The count is : "+n);
if (n>0) {
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

I know i'm missing something. Can anyone help me, where i'm getting wrong ?

Comment: can u provide demo for ur file....

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, you just need to put it on the submit event handler and prevent default if n=0

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf Dude. Can you please give me a sample code ?

Comment: I need a bit more code to help you, at least your form :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution to my own question. The below script is working fine.

```
var n = $('input[name="claimListView.claimStatus"]:checkbox:checked').length;
if (n>0) {
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```